# Listing directories on Lighttpd running on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, lighttpd

I newly migrated from Apache to Lighttpd and it runs much faster. But when I type in directories it sends me `404 - Not Found`.

Is there a way to list files again? I left everything there default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, listing directories is disabled.  You have to enable it in your lighttpd.conf with:

dir-listing.activate = "enable"